# find specific values from subarray in mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find, sub-array

i just want the values with year 1976 from the data

```
{
        "_id" : "625305190f48a6512a18220d",
        "artist" : "AC/DC",
        "albums" : [
                {
                        "title" : "High Voltage",
                        "year" : 1976
                },
                {
                        "title" : "Back in Black",
                        "year" : 1980
                },
                {
                        "title" : "Dirty Deeds Done Dirt Cheap",
                        "year" : 1976
                },
                {
                        "title" : "Highway to Hell",
                        "year" : 1979
                }
        ],
        "singers" : "Bon Scott"
}
```

what i tried first i insert using this statements

```
db.getCollection('first').insertMany([])
```

and then to filter out with year 1976 the following code

```
db.first.findOne({"albums.year":1976})
```

and got this output:

```
{
        "_id" : "625305190f48a6512a18220d",
        "artist" : "AC/DC",
        "albums" : [
                {
                        "title" : "High Voltage",
                        "year" : 1976
                },
                {
                        "title" : "Back in Black",
                        "year" : 1980
                },
                {
                        "title" : "Dirty Deeds Done Dirt Cheap",
                        "year" : 1976
                },
                {
                        "title" : "Highway to Hell",
                        "year" : 1979
                }
        ],
        "singers" : "Bon Scott"
}
```

why is it giving years which are not 1976 i want filter only the year which are 1976

Answer (score 0):

`$project` after `find`

```
db.collection.find({
  "albums.year": 1976
},
{
  "albums.$": 1
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NZ-CzmyrGL8)